# How do I edit an encrypted data bag with Chef?

Tags: encryption, chef-infra

I am using Chef 12.14.60. I am trying to edit multiple times an encrypted databag. I seem to only be able to edit it when I encrypt it with a secret. After that I get this error:

> ERROR: Chef::Exceptions::ValidationFailed: Option data_bag's value
>   {"encrypted_data"=>"pyVTbbahq1IW2syF24xzsAfSZdzOwVq1vZIlr2ssp9M=\n",
>   "iv"=>"Sk/fVdGNnTti5EW6f5o3Ow==\n", "version"=>1,
>   "cipher"=>"aes-256-cbc"} does not match regular expression
>   /^[-[:alnum:]_]+$/

I run this to create the databag and item:

```
$ knife data bag create db123 foobar
```

I run this to encrypt the databag's item:

```
$ knife data bag edit db123 foobar --secret goodpassword
```

I see "Encrypting data bag using provided secret." as a result.

I run this to try to edit the databag again:

```
$ knife data bag edit db123 foobar --secret goodpassword
```

But then I see this:

> ERROR: Chef::Exceptions::ValidationFailed: Option data_bag's value
>   {"encrypted_data"=>"4l9TyNv+987JfePFfMLdELVlDuia938kAnwrly9XW94=\n",
>   "iv"=>"JZL76EtebsSXUeE1m5KT9w==\n", "version"=>1,
>   "cipher"=>"aes-256-cbc"} does not match regular expression
>   /^[-[:alnum:]_]+$/

I expect the ability to edit an encrypted databag if I use the correct password.  How do I edit the foobar item in my db123 data bag again?